# function array_agg(text) is not unique when connecting with pgAdmin III

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

When I connect to PostgreSQL database with pgAdmin III (1.22.2), I get this error:

```
ERROR:  function array_agg(text) is not unique
LINE 5: (SELECT array_agg(label) FROM pg_shseclabel sl1 WHERE sl1.ob...
                 ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The database server is PostgreSQL 9.6.

Same instance of pgAdmin works fine with databases running PostgreSQL 9.0 versions.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found that problem is caused by migration from 9.0 to 9.6.

Log in to the database using psql and run `\df array_agg`. This is how it should look in 9.0:

```
db=# \df array_agg
                           List of functions
   Schema   |   Name    | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------+------
 pg_catalog | array_agg | anyarray         | anyelement          | agg
(1 row)
```

and in 9.6:

```
db=# \df array_agg
                           List of functions
   Schema   |   Name    | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------+------
 pg_catalog | array_agg | anyarray         | anyarray            | agg
 pg_catalog | array_agg | anyarray         | anynonarray         | agg
(2 rows)
```

However, when I ran `\df array_agg` on my server, I get:

```
db=> \df array_agg
                                Lista funkcji
  Schemat   |   Nazwa   | Typ danych wyniku | Typy danych argumentów |  Typ  
------------+-----------+-------------------+------------------------+-------
 pg_catalog | array_agg | anyarray          | anyarray               | agreg
 pg_catalog | array_agg | anyarray          | anynonarray            | agreg
 public     | array_agg | anyarray          | anyelement             | agreg
(3 rows)
```

As mentioned [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/a6c00e7edf434fa0b3d0be1b28b1617a%40EXCH1.WEATHERTOP.local), it can be fixed by:

```
DROP AGGREGATE public.array_agg(anyelement);
```

Comment: it showed up on some 9.4s last week. same fix worked. not sure what the cause was.

Comment: but I have a theory stored functions call array_agg so maybe a minor point upgrade in postgres changed the type of array_agg and the dependancies caused the duplication... if that's the case naughty devs!.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, explicitly typecasting the argument to either `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` works.

E.g.,

`SELECT array_agg('Group1');`

Results in:

```
ERROR:  function array_agg(unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: SELECT array_agg('Group1');
               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42725
Character: 8
```

However, both of

`SELECT array_agg('Group1'::VARCHAR);`

and

`SELECT array_agg('Group1'::TEXT);`

work as expected and return the respective `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` array.